# ProcessWire foreach loop to show 4 colums in each row

Tags: php, html, css, processwire

I've been working on the website for quite a while now and stumbled upon a problem in creating specific foreach loop. I am using ProcessWire to create CMS for the website. I want to display 4 columns in each row, but I am baffled. Here is my code so far;

```
<div class="container">
<? $count == 0; ?>      
        <? foreach($page->events_tickets as $cols): ?>
        <!-- portfolio item -->
        <? if ($count % 4 == 0)
            echo "<div class='row'>";
        ?>
            <? for($count = 0; $count < 4; $count++) { ?>
            <div class="span3  project-item graphics box">
                <div class="thumbnail" >
                    <!-- IMAGE CONTAINER-->
                    <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="<?=$cols->event_url;?>" title="portfolio image">
                        <img src="<?=$cols->event_img->url;?>" alt="<?=$cols->event_img->description;?>" /> 
                    </a>
                    <!--END IMAGE CONTAINER-->
                    <!-- CAPTION --> 
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4 class=""><?=$cols->event_title;?></h4>
                            <p class="caption-descr" id="opening-reception" style="height: 190px; overflow:auto;">
                            <?=$cols->event_desc;?> <a href="<?=$cols->event_url;?>" target="_blank" style="" title=""> BUY TICKETS</a> 
                            </p>    
                    </div><!--END CAPTION --> 
                </div><!-- END: THUMBNAIL -->
            </div><!-- END: portfolio item -->
            <? if($count % 1 = 1 ) break;} ?>
            </div>  <!--END OF ROW-->
        <? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I eventually found out how to solve it. Instead using nested loops I decided to run the loop through conditional if else statement.

```
<div class="row">
            <? foreach($page->events_tickets as $cols): ?>
            <? if($cols->event_num % 4 != 0) {?>
            <!-- portfolio item -->
                <div class="span3  project-item graphics box">
                    <div class="thumbnail" >
                        <!-- IMAGE CONTAINER-->
                        <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="<?=$cols->event_url;?>" title="portfolio image">
                            <img src="<?=$cols->event_img->url;?>" alt="<?=$cols->event_img->description;?>" /> 
                        </a>
                        <!--END IMAGE CONTAINER-->
                        <!-- CAPTION --> 
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class=""><?=$cols->event_title;?></h4>
                                <p class="caption-descr" id="opening-reception" style="height: 190px; overflow:auto;">
                                <?=$cols->event_desc;?> <a href="<?=$cols->event_url;?>" target="_blank" style="" title=""> BUY TICKETS</a> 
                                </p>    
                        </div><!--END CAPTION --> 
                    </div><!-- END: THUMBNAIL -->
                </div><!-- END: portfolio item -->

            <? } else if($cols->event_num%4 == 0) {?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3  project-item graphics box">
                        <div class="thumbnail" >
                            <!-- IMAGE CONTAINER-->
                            <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="<?=$cols->event_url;?>" title="portfolio image">
                                <img src="<?=$cols->event_img->url;?>" alt="<?=$cols->event_img->description;?>" /> 
                            </a>
                            <!--END IMAGE CONTAINER-->
                            <!-- CAPTION --> 
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class=""><?=$cols->event_title;?></h4>
                                    <p class="caption-descr" id="opening-reception" style="height: 190px; overflow:auto;">
                                    <?=$cols->event_desc;?> <a href="<?=$cols->event_url;?>" target="_blank" style="" title=""> BUY TICKETS</a> 
                                    </p>    
                            </div><!--END CAPTION --> 
                        </div><!-- END: THUMBNAIL -->
                    </div><!-- END: portfolio item -->
                    </div>  <!--END OF ROW-->
                <? } ?> 
            <? endforeach; ?>
        </div>  <!--END OF ROW-->
```

I added extra field to the `events_tickets` field and called it `events_num`. `events_num` starts with 1 and follows along until the end of the records.`<? if($cols->event_num % 4 != 0) {?>` then display the 4 columns. Then if number reached 5 the remainder when divided by 4 is odd number, thus it creates `<div class="row">` and displays 4 more columns. Then this procedure continues. Thus there is no need in creating nested loop.